# Reading from a XML file with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read from a XML file and save information into a Dictionary.

This is how my XML looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<testUI_root>

  <!--Information for the first coded UI Test-->
  <codedUITest name ="CodedUITestMethod1">

    <description name ="Entering username from CSV" key = "1"/>
    <description name ="Entering password from CSV" key = "2"/>
    <description name ="Clicking exit" key ="3"/>

  </codedUITest>


</testUI_root>
```

So I am trying to read and save to a Dictionary, this is how I have tried :

```
            //Load xml
            //StringBuilder description = new StringBuilder();
            int key;
            Dictionary<int, string> valDic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");


            //Run query
            var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("codedUITest")
                       where lv1.Attribute("name").Value.Contains("CodedUITestMethod1")
                       select new
                       {
                           key = lv1.Descendants("key"),
                           value = lv1.Descendants("name")
                       };
            //loop
            foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
            {
                foreach (var lv2_k in lv1.key)
                {
                   //it's not entering into this loop
                    foreach (var lv2_v in lv1.value)
                    {
                        // isn't entering here either
                        key = Convert.ToInt32(lv2_k.Attribute("key").ToString());
                        valDic.Add(key, lv2_v.Attribute("name").ToString());
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> abc in valDic)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Value: " + abc.ToString());
            }
```

There is no syntax error, it's a logical one.
So this is how my dictionary is supposed to look like.

```
/*
1.Entering Username from CSV
2.Entering password from CSV
3.Clicking exit
*/
```

Saved the xml to output directory. ( from vs )
Tried the code in LinqPad, "query is successful" but no output.
I barely have any experience with Linq, I apologize in advance if this matter/error was a simple one.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `ToDictionary` method

```
xdoc.Descendants("codedUITest")
.Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value.Contains("CodedUITestMethod1"))
.Elements("description")
.ToDictionary(x => (int)x.Attribute("key"), x => (string)x.Attribute("name"));
```

Comment: It is working, I'll accept the answer in one minute...
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

use XML serialization instead.  using xsd.exe that comes with visual studio, you can represent your XML code as the following c# business object:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class testUI_root {

    private testUI_rootCodedUITest[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("codedUITest", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public testUI_rootCodedUITest[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class testUI_rootCodedUITest {

    private testUI_rootCodedUITestDescription[] descriptionField;

    private string nameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("description", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public testUI_rootCodedUITestDescription[] description {
        get {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class testUI_rootCodedUITestDescription {

    private string nameField;

    private string keyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string name {
        get {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set {
            this.nameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string key {
        get {
            return this.keyField;
        }
        set {
            this.keyField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

then from there, you can read the XML into a business object:

```
testUI_root theReturn = null;
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer s = null;
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(thePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
    if (fs.Length > 0) {
        using (System.Xml.XmlTextReader r = new XmlTextReader(fs)) {
            s = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(testUI_root));
            theReturn = (testUI_root)s.Deserialize(r);
        }
    }
}
return theReturn;
```

and there you have a business object representation of your XML!  From there it should be pretty easy to use link to search through the object to find values you want.  This is just a quick mock up of how to do what you want, so i haven't tested it, but hopefully it'll lead you down the right path.